# libreoffice python access Property object

Tags: python, libreoffice

Given this Property of the variable `properties` acquired in this way

```
view_settings = current_controller.ViewSettings
property_set=view_settings.getPropertySetInfo()
properties=property_set.getProperties()
```

How do I access the values.

For example:

```
 (com.sun.star.beans.Property){ Name = (string)"ZoomValue", Handle = (long)0x1b, Type = (type)short, Attributes = (short)0x0 }
```

These fail :

```
properties.ZoomValue
properties.getattr('ZoomValue')
properties['ZoomValue']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you got a little lost.  This is enough to get the value.

```
view_settings = current_controller.ViewSettings
view_settings.ZoomValue
```

[getPropertySetInfo()](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/interfacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1beans_1_1XPropertySet.html#ae66b2a18e5d6d8ac8928e3feef1d5475) tells *information* about the properties rather than giving access to the property values. For example you could determine the property type like this:

```
propinfo = property_set.getPropertyByName('ZoomValue')
propinfo.Type
```

Result:

```
<Type instance short (<Enum instance com.sun.star.uno.TypeClass ('SHORT')>)>
```